# UBJSON: Parsing an array of bytes with no specified length?

Tags: json, parsing

In the specification of UBJSON, it states that an array can optionally have a length. However, if you have an array of bytes, i.e.:

```
[
    12
    2
    93 // = ASCII ']'
    4
]
```

How do you know for certain that the ']' byte you have seen is definitely the actual closing brace, and not just an arbitrary byte=93 found in the array? If the length of this array is optional, how can this be done in UBJSON?